# Why does a subtype of AbstractArray result in imprecise matrix operations in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia, floating-accuracy

I'm currently working on creating a subtype of `AbstractArray` in Julia, which allows you to store a vector in addition to an Array itself. You can think of it as the column "names", with element types as a subtype of `AbstractFloat`. Hence, it has some similarities to the [NamedArray.jl](https://github.com/davidavdav/NamedArrays.jl) package, but restricts to only assigning the columns with Floats (in case of matrices).

The struct that I've created so far (following the [guide](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-array) to create a subtype of `AbstractArray`) is defined as follows:

```
struct FooArray{T, N, AT, VT} <: AbstractArray{T, N}
    data::AT
    vec::VT
    function FooArray(data::AbstractArray{T1, N}, vec::AbstractVector{T2}) where {T1 <: AbstractFloat, T2 <: AbstractFloat, N}
        length(vec) == size(data, 2) || error("Inconsistent dimensions")
        new{T1, N, typeof(data), typeof(vec)}(data, vec)
    end
end
@inline Base.@propagate_inbounds Base.getindex(fooarr::FooArray, i::Int) = getindex(fooarr.data, i)
@inline Base.@propagate_inbounds Base.getindex(fooarr::FooArray, I::Vararg{Int, 2}) = getindex(fooarr.data, I...)
@inline Base.@propagate_inbounds Base.size(fooarr::FooArray) = size(fooarr.data)
Base.IndexStyle(::Type{<:FooArray}) = IndexLinear()
```

This already seems to be enough to create objects of type `fooArray` and do some simple math with it. However, I've observed that some essential functions such as matrix-vector multiplications seem to be imprecise. For example, the following should consistently return a vector of `0.0`, but:

```
R = rand(100, 3)
S = FooArray(R, collect(1.0:3.0))
y = rand(100)
S'y - R'y
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 -7.105427357601002e-15
 0.0
 3.552713678800501e-15
```

While the differences are very small, they can quickly add up over many different calculations, leading to significant errors.

Where do these differences come from?

A look at the calculations via macro `@code_llvm` reveals that appearently different `matmul` functions from `LinearAlgebra` are used (with other minor differences):

```
@code_llvm S'y
   ...
   @ C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\LinearAlgebra\src\matmul.jl:111 within `*'
   ...
@code_llvm S'y
   ...
   @ C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.6\LinearAlgebra\src\matmul.jl:106 within `*'
   ...
```

Redefining the `adjoint` and `*` functions on our `FooArray` object provides the expected, correct result:

```
import Base: *, adjoint, /
Base.adjoint(a::FooArray) = FooArray(a.data', zeros(size(a.data, 1)))
*(a::FooArray{T, 2, AT, VT} where {AT, VT}, b::AbstractVector{S}) where {T, S} = a.data * b
S'y - R'y
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0
```

However, this solution (which is also done in `NamedArrays` [here](https://github.com/davidavdav/NamedArrays.jl/blob/main/src/arithmetic.jl)) would require defining and maintaining all sorts of functions, not just the standard functions in `base`, adding more and more dependencies just because of this small error margin.

Is there any simpler way to get rid of this issue without redefining every operation and possibly many other functions from other packages?

I'm using Julia version 1.6.1 on Windows 64-bit system.

Comment: Isn't this just https://0.30000000000000004.com/?

Comment: I can't run the posted code. At first I just thought it was a missed correction at `fooarr.mat`, but after I changed it to `fooarr.data`, attempting `S'y - R'y` causes a `StackOverflowError` due to `getindex(...i::Int64)` recursion.

Comment: @OscarSmith The intent for the type seems to be wrapping the matrix, as the redefinitions forwards from `arr` to `arr.data`. The first approach tries to do that element by element through `getindex`, so it doesn't seem like there should be a discrepancy.

Comment: Side note: a type name starting with a lowercase letter is a bit irritating. Stylistically.

Comment: @BatWannaBe indeed, there were some errors in the code. I've edited the original post, the code should now be runnable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the implementation of matrix multiplication will vary depending upon your array type.  The builtin `Array` will use BLAS, whereas your custom `fooArray` will use a generic implementation, and due to the non-associativity of floating point arithmetic, these different approaches will indeed yield different values — and note that they *may be different from the ground truth, even for the builtin `Array`s!*

```
julia> using Random; Random.seed!(0); R = rand(100, 3); y = rand(100);

julia> R'y - Float64.(big.(R)'big.(y))
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 -3.552713678800501e-15
  0.0
  0.0
```

You may be able to implement your custom array as a `DenseArray`, which will ensure that it uses the same (BLAS-enabled) codepath.  You just [need to implement a few more methods](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-strided-arrays), most importantly `strides` and `unsafe_convert`:

```
julia> struct FooArray{T, N} <: DenseArray{T, N}
          data::Array{T, N}
       end
       Base.getindex(fooarr::FooArray, i::Int) = fooarr.data[i]
       Base.size(fooarr::FooArray) = size(fooarr.data)
       Base.IndexStyle(::Type{<:FooArray}) = IndexLinear()
       Base.strides(fooarr::FooArray) = strides(fooarr.data)
       Base.unsafe_convert(P::Type{Ptr{T}}, fooarr::FooArray{T}) where {T} = Base.unsafe_convert(P, fooarr.data)

julia> R = rand(100, 3); S = FooArray(R); y = rand(100)
       R'y - S'y
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.0
 0.0
 0.0

julia> R = rand(100, 1000); S = FooArray(R); y = rand(100)
       R'y == S'y
true
```

Comment: So if BLAS is not doing operations in the generic linear order, what is it doing? Is it parallel?

Comment: @BatWannaBe I believe both implementations traverse the array in a SIMD-friendly cache-optimized access pattern, which simultaneously improves both performance and accuracy over the naive triple `for` loop.  They just do so slightly differently.

Comment: @mbauman Thank you very much for the explanation. Interesting that subtyping `DenseArray` uses BLAS, but as `AbstractArray` not. The difference is also very notable in computation time for larger matrices, so using BLAS instead of the generic multiplication should be preferable anyways.

Comment: small addendum to this solution: some functions using `mapreduce` such as `sum` or `mean` still can exhibit a similar error, e.g. `sum(R, dims = 1) - sum(S, dims = 1)` is still not equal to zero. A very simple solution is to enable fast linear indexing:
`import Base: has_fast_linear_indexing`
`has_fast_linear_indexing(fooarr::FooArray) = true`